# Loop through a directory on a windows minion using Salt State

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I need to work with folders and files in a directory on a minion not master. This is what I have tried but it's not working. Unfortunately, salt documentation is not very explicit in their examples.

```
{% set folderLocation = 'D:\\Myfolder' %} 
{% for folder in folderLocation %}
  {% if folder == "Something" %}
      DeleteFolder:
          file.absent:
              - name = 'D:\\Myfolder\\folder' 
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Basically, I want to get the content of Myfolder like how you use `Get-Item/Get-ChildItem 'D:\\Myfolder'` in powershell and then loop through it. How can I achieve this please in a salt state? I want to avoid using cmd.script or cmd.run. "Myfolder" is on the minion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `file.find` [module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html#salt.modules.file.find) to get the contents of a given path.

For a simple operation like delete, that you have shown in the question, you can write it as (without having to iterate):

```yaml
delete-myfolder-files:
  module.run:
    - file.find:
        - path: "D:/MyFolder/"
        - mindepth: 1
        - delete: fd
```

The above state will `delete` all files and directories (represented by `fd`), in the given `path`, but excluding the base directory because of `mindepth`.

You could also save the results of the "find" operation into a variable, and use it.

```
{% set dir_contents = salt['file.find'](path="D:/MyFolder/", type="fd", mindepth=1) %}

{% for item in dir_contents %}
# Do something
{% endfor %}
```

Now the `dir_contents` variable will have an array of files and directories (specified by `type`). We can iterate over each "item" and do something else with it